# Как реализовать подключение сокета сначала к одному серверу, а потом к другому

Tags: сеть, tcp-ip, qt, c++, сокет

Здравствуйте. Поясню суть проблемы. В общем у меня есть задача - подключиться к серверу. Этот сервер мне вернет IP и PORT сервера для авторизации. То есть дальше мне надо подключится к считанному серверу для авторизации. Конечно можно просто отключится от первого сервера и подключится к другому, но вот как быть с сигналами и слотами? Они ведь будут заточены только под один из серверов. Объясните пожалуйста как сделать то что я хочу.

Comment: Вам сокетов жалко ? Создайте еще 1

Comment: Насколько я знаю TCP (в \*nix)  уже законнектившийся сокет повторно использовать в другом соединении нельзя. 

Если соединение больше не нужно закрывайте сокет.

Comment: @avp А где можно повторно использовать уже законнектившийся сокет?

Comment: @Леха Емельяненко Я не знаю qt, но подозреваю, что ряд терминов в вопросе -- оттуда. Только мне сложно представить библиотеку, которая бы так ограничивала программиста. Вы можете создать ещё сокет, не закрывая текущего. Соединения в http поддерживаются с помощью cookies, поэтому Вам придётся озадачиться их получением/передачей. Если Вас волнует вопрос, как синхронизировать работу с несколькими соединениями -- так это вопрос другой. В qt, кажется, есть свои (дефакто стандартные) механизмы

Comment: @alexlz, не знаю. 

Видимо не очень ясно выразился в комментарии. Суть высказывания, что работу с TCP в \*nix-ах я знаю лучше, чем в других системах.

Comment: А в других системах она сделана по образцу *nix, поскольку реализует те же самые протоколы. (Вспомните select в винсокете)

Comment: Я тоже думаю, что похоже. 

Но, IMHO ничто не мешает реализовать `disconnect(int sock)`, сохраняющий все уже заданные `setsoskopt()` режимы, но мне такой вызов неизвестен.

Comment: Сложно представить работу такой системы. А пока наоборот, даже для http (начиная с 4.0 кажется) стараются соединения не рвать.

Comment: @alexlz, если честно, не вижу никакой связи между KeepAlive в hhtp (IMHO 1.1) и работой системы с (предполагаемым) disconnect().

Иногда после вызова socket() и до connect() делают несколько setsockopt(). При закрытии соединения и открытии нового (например, с другим сервером) приходится брать новый сокет и задавать ему те же опции, что и предыдущему. Вот disconnect просто позволил бы использовать уже готовый сокет (возможно включая shutdown предыдущего соединения).

Но это все так, теоретический треп.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Покурите примеры, доки. Макса Шлее в конце концов. И вам сразу всё станет понятно. Если вы спотыкаетесь на таких простых вопросах, то что же будет дальше.

**UPD**

С сигналами и слотами ничего не будет. Просто отключайте сокет от сервера и от сигналов по завершении передачи.

```
void QLoader::onDisconnectFromServer(){
    tcpSocket->disconnectFromHost();
    tcpSocket->disconnect(this);
}
```

Обрабатываете данные и подключаетесь уже к другому серверу.

```
tcpSocket->connectToHost(IP, PORT);
connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(connected()),this, SLOT(onConnected()));
connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(onDisconnected()));
connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(onReadyRead()));
connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
    this, SLOT(onError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
connect (tcpSocket, SIGNAL(readChannelFinished(), this, SLOT(onFinished()));
```

Оберните это в класс и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Достойный ответ kR00toго xAckErA. А что такое Макс Шлее? Я тоже хочу, чтобы мне стало всё понятно.

Comment: Это автор очень хорошей книжульки по Qt. 
http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4777403/

Comment: Да, ответ хорош. Суть: я сам не знаю, но слышал, что есть крутые книжки... (потом предлагает приобрести ее за 989.00 руб. в Озоне)

При этом утверждается, что вопрос простой.

Comment: Ну в инете книжка лежит и в файлах. Правда я не знаю, насколько законно оттуда её скачивать. А в современном УК есть очень интересные статьи

Comment: @alexlz, а книжка то стоящая? 

Или полтыщи страниц для начинающих плюс текст всех man-ов по теме?

Comment: @avp не читал и даже не смотрел. Увы.

И насчёт http. Вроде понял. Но опять же, ситуация, когда параметры надо сохранять между соединениями, по-моему, весьма редкая.

А keep-alive -- он из http/1.0. В 1.1 persistent connections уже по умолчанию, там надо специально указывать, что соединение закрывается (только по буквам не помню, а искать лень)

Comment: Я уверяю, книжка стоящая. Сам начал изучение Qt именно с неё. Обязательно прочитайте (скачайте уже наконец, в гугле же вас не забанили).